# Remap [zen-garden] --> [pvz-zen-garden]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

What is a zen garden? Is there a game called "Zen Garden"? Not that I've heard of.

## REQUEST

REMAP [zen-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zen-garden) TO [pvz-zen-garden](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pvz-zen-garden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only 4 questions, and it's a simple but well-integrated part of the game.  It doesn't warrant its own tag; it should just be removed.

Comment: I can burninates?

Comment: @JeffreyLin Quick edits on these shouldn't be a problem, go for it :)

Comment: .....Dones.....